# spring mvc module not updating record

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

In a spring mvc application that uses hibernate an jpa, I have a module for editing phone numbers which is not committing changes to the database when the user enters altered information for phone number and phone number type.  I keep going over the code, but I cannot see where the problem is.  Can someone show me what to change in the below?

Here are the relevant methods of PhoneNumberController.java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/phonenumbers/{phonenumberId}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initUpdateForm(@PathVariable("phonenumberId") int phonenumberId, Map<String, Object> model) {
    System.out.println("--------------------------------- made it into initUpdateForm() method");
    PhoneNumber phonenumber = this.clinicService.findPhoneNumberById(phonenumberId);
    model.put("phonenumber", phonenumber);
    return "phonenumbers/createOrUpdatePhoneNumberForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/phonenumbers/{phonenumberId}/edit", method = {RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.POST})
public String processUpdateForm(@ModelAttribute("phonenumber") PhoneNumber phonenumber, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    // we're not using @Valid annotation here because it is easier to define such validation rule in Java
    new PhoneNumberValidator().validate(phonenumber, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {return "phonenumbers/createOrUpdatePhoneNumberForm";}
    else {
        this.clinicService.savePhoneNumber(phonenumber);
        status.setComplete();
        return "redirect:/patients?patientID={patientId}&type=phone";
    }
}
```

Here is the PhoneNumber.java model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "patient_phone_numbers")
public class PhoneNumber {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
private Patient patient;

@Column(name="phonenumber")
private String number;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "type_id")
private PhoneNumberType type;

@Column(name = "preferred")
private boolean preferred;

@Column(name = "okmessages")
private boolean okmessages;

public Integer getId(){return id;}
public void setId(Integer i){id=i;}

protected void setPatient(Patient patient) {this.patient = patient;}
public Patient getPatient(){return this.patient;}

public String getNumber(){return number;}
public void setNumber(String pn){number=pn;}

public PhoneNumberType getType(){return this.type;}
public void setType(PhoneNumberType nt){this.type=nt;}

public boolean getPreferred(){return preferred;}
public void setPreferred(boolean p){preferred=p;}

public boolean getOkmessages(){return okmessages;}
public void setOkmessages(boolean m){okmessages=m;}

public boolean isNew() {return (this.id == null);}
}
```

And here is the createOrUpdatePhoneNumberForm.jsp:

```
<html lang="en">
<jsp:include page="../fragments/headTag.jsp"/>
<body>
<div class="container">
<jsp:include page="../fragments/bodyHeader.jsp"/>
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${phonenumber['new']}">
        <c:set var="method" value="post"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="method" value="put"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<h2>
    <c:if test="${phonenumber['new']}">New </c:if>
    Phone Number
</h2>

<form:form modelAttribute="phonenumber" method="${method}" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group" id="patient">
        <label class="control-label">Patient </label>
        <c:out value="${phonenumber.patient.firstName} ${phonenumber.patient.lastName}"/>
    </div>

    <petclinic:inputField label="PhoneNumber" name="number"/>
    <div class="control-group">
        <petclinic:selectField name="type" label="Type" names="${numtypes}" size="5"/>
    </div>
    Preferred number? <form:checkbox path="preferred"/><br>
    OK to leave messages? <form:checkbox path="okmessages"/>
    <td>
    </td>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${phonenumber['new']}">
                <button type="submit">Add Phone Number</button>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <button type="submit">Update Phone Number</button> <h3>    Link to delete will go here.</h3>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </div>
</form:form>
<c:if test="${!phonenumber['new']}">
</c:if>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

ClinicService.java is:

```
@Service
public class ClinicServiceImpl implements ClinicService {

private DocumentRepository documentRepository;
private PatientRepository patientRepository;
private AddressRepository addressRepository;
private PhoneNumberRepository phoneNumberRepository;

@Autowired
public ClinicServiceImpl(DocumentRepository documentRepository, PatientRepository patientRepository, AddressRepository addressRepository, PhoneNumberRepository phoneNumberRepository) {
    this.documentRepository = documentRepository;
    this.patientRepository = patientRepository;
    this.addressRepository = addressRepository;
    this.phoneNumberRepository = phoneNumberRepository;
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Collection<DocumentType> findDocumentTypes() throws DataAccessException {return documentRepository.findDocumentTypes();}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Collection<Gender> findGenders() throws DataAccessException {return patientRepository.findGenders();}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Collection<Race> findRaces() throws DataAccessException {return patientRepository.findRaces();}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Patient findPatientById(int id) throws DataAccessException {return patientRepository.findById(id);}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Collection<Patient> findPatientByLastName(String lastName) throws DataAccessException {return patientRepository.findByLastName(lastName);}

@Override
@Transactional
public void savePatient(Patient patient) throws DataAccessException {
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------- inside clinicservice.savePatient()");
    patientRepository.save(patient);}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Document findDocumentById(int id) throws DataAccessException {
    System.out.println("--------------- made it into clinicservice.findDocumentById() method");
    return documentRepository.findById(id);}

@Override
@Transactional
public void saveDocument(Document doc) throws DataAccessException {documentRepository.save(doc);}

@Override
@Transactional
public void saveAddress(Address addr) throws DataAccessException {addressRepository.save(addr);}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Address findAddressById(int id) throws DataAccessException {return addressRepository.findById(id);}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Collection<State> findStates() throws DataAccessException {return addressRepository.findStates();}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Collection<PhoneNumberType> findPhoneNumberTypes() throws DataAccessException {return phoneNumberRepository.findPhoneNumberTypes();}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void savePhoneNumber(PhoneNumber pn) throws DataAccessException {
    System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++ inside savePhoneNumber(pn) : "+pn.getNumber()+" , "+pn.getType().getName());
    phoneNumberRepository.save(pn);
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public PhoneNumber findPhoneNumberById(int id) throws DataAccessException {return phoneNumberRepository.findById(id);}
}
```

JpaPhoneNumberRepository.java contains the following:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public void save(PhoneNumber phonenumber) {
    System.out.println("------------------------------ inside save(phonenumber) : "+phonenumber.getNumber()+" , "+phonenumber.getType().getName());
    if (phonenumber.getId() == null) {
        System.out.println("phonenumber.getId() == null ");
        this.em.persist(phonenumber);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("else");
        this.em.merge(phonenumber);}
}
```

The correct new values for `getNumber()` and `getType().getName()` print out.  And `"else"` prints out, but then the data is not updated in the database.  Why not?  (note that clinicservice calls this `save()` method of `JpaPhoneNumberRepository.java`.)

Comment: have you put in a `System.out` in `processUpdateForm` before saving it to make sure the changes from the form are being applied? You can eliminate half of your search right there.

Comment: And what's `clinicService`? A Spring JPA repository? Are you implementing any methods yourself?

Comment: @chrylis ClinicService code can be seen at the following link, though I have edited it a bit to work with phone numbers and the like:  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/tree/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/service

Comment: Please post *your own code*. The whole issue is with your modifications to the Pet Clinic app, particularly your `savePhoneNumber` method.

Comment: @chrylis I just added the relevant method from JpaPhoneNumberRepository.java which is printing out the correctly updated values just before the code which should be updating the data in the entitymanager.  What else do you need in order to find the problem?

Comment: @chrylis Is the issue in a config file setting somewhere? The structure of `petclinic` is relevant here because it might indicate where I would need to change settings for a new model object `PhoneNumber`.

Comment: You're calling `savePhoneNumber`, which is in `clientService`. Please post *that*. Additionally, turn up your logging and see what the request flow looks like. Is it actually returning a 200 series result? Is it redirecting? Or is it throwing a 500 that you're ignoring?

Comment: @chrylis I just posted `savePhoneNumber` in `clientService` above.  The code is returning `/patients?patientID=1&type=phone` but with the old value of the `phone number` and `type`, NOT the new value. Please explain specific instructions for logging, because I do not know what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have *ClinicServiceImpl* > *savePhoneNumber* method annotated as **@Transactional(readOnly = true)**. Change it to **@Transactional**

Answer (score 1):

Why is the savePhoneNumber method in your ClinicService.java as **@Transactional(readOnly=True)**?
That is the cause of the problem